# Trouble rendering a partial view on the same page as main view using Ajax.ActionLink()

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my index view I have several Ajax.ActionLinks displayed as shown in the code below. I am trying to render a partial view into DIV section when one of those links is clicked. Right now, it is rendering the partial as its own page. What am I doing incorrectly?

**View**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
...Other HTML
<article class="border c-two" style="background-image: url('/Content/images/Fancy.jpg')">
    <div style="opacity: 0;" class="fdw-background">
        <h4 style="color:#fff;">Fancy Schmancy</h4>
        <p class="fdw-port">
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Go Now", "GotoStore", "Simulation", new { id = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Rest", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, HttpMethod = "GET" })<span class="vg-icon">→</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</article>
...other  HTML
<div id="Rest"></div>
```

**Controller**

```
public PartialViewResult GotoStore(int id)
{
    Store store = db.Stores.Find(id);
    return PartialView(store);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried InserionMode.Replace?

Comment: Just tried it, and I get the same result.

Comment: is the request fired via ajax, if you look at the network tab of chrome or ie debugging tools and see if it is indeed fired by jquery or if a full request has happened

Comment: It shows the initiator as "Other" when I click the action link. Is this what you mean?

Comment: However, in the Source tab in chrome, it shows that I am getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError" error within jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working. The problem was where I added in the script source.

This:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Needs to be placed inside your layout file towards the bottom like this:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```